# Changing the title of an alert button maliciously

Tags: ios, security

Is it possible for a malicious developer to interchange ok and cancel in the title of an alert button? In other words, "ok" means cancel, "cancel" means ok.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/alerts/

Comment: Probably, why? you want to do it?

Comment: It's entirely up the developer what the consequence of pressing each button is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the developer wants to interchange the labels or purpose of an alert's buttons, they can.

This is also possible without malicious intent. A mistake or error in the code written by the developer can create this behaviour.